# How can I print the three statements of pw.println only once although I run the program many times

Tags: java

I'm trying to print `pw.println` statements only once even though I am running the program many times. Is there any solution?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
 Scanner a=new Scanner (System.in);
 String First_Name , Last_Name, Address , E_mail , Department;
 int Password;
 System.out.println("ENTER FIRST NAME: ");
 First_Name=a.next();
 System.out.println("ENTER LAST NAME: ");
 Last_Name=a.next();
 System.out.println("ENTER ADDRESS: ");
 Address=a.next();
 System.out.println("ENTER E_MAIL: ");
 E_mail=a.next();
 System.out.println("ENTER DEPARTMENT: ");
 Department=a.next();
 System.out.println("ENTER PASSWORD: ");
 Password=a.nextInt();      
 FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\STUD_INFO.txt" , true);
 PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter (fw);
 pw.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tSTUDENT INFORMATION");
 pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
 pw.println("First_Name" + "\t\t    " + "Last_Name" + "\t\t    " + "Address" + "\t\t    " + "E_mail" + "\t\t    " + "Department" + "\t\t    " + "Password");
 pw.println(First_Name   + "\t\t\t    " + Last_Name + "\t\t    " + Address + "\t\t    " + E_mail + "\t    " + Department + "\t\t\t    " + Password);  
 pw.close();
}
```

Comment: Only run it once?

Comment: Check whether the destination file already exists and is not empty/contains the values you want to write?

Comment: @Elliot Frisch yes , every time i run the program , "student information" statement appears and i want it to be viewed once ,

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool it exists , my problem is about how to print the statement for only one time ^^

Comment: Crusha's suggestions is correct. Use an if statement to check if the file already exists and if it does, don't print the lines you don't want.

Comment: @mkasberg  how can i do this using if ??

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply delete the file if it already exists:

```
Files.deleteIfExists("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\STUD_INFO.txt"); //deletes the file

FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\STUD_INFO.txt" , true);
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter (fw);
pw.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tSTUDENT INFORMATION");
pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
pw.println("First_Name" + "\t\t    " + "Last_Name" + "\t\t    " + "Address" + "\t\t    " + "E_mail" + "\t\t    " + "Department" + "\t\t    " + "Password");
pw.println(First_Name   + "\t\t\t    " + Last_Name + "\t\t    " + Address + "\t\t    " + E_mail + "\t    " + Department + "\t\t\t    " + Password);  
pw.close();
```

Comment: I believe his intention is to append to the end of the file without adding the headers each time. Deleting the file each time won't necessarily solve that problem.

Comment: Yes, may be. In that case a check for existence is the way to go.

Comment: @mkasberg , THANK YOU so much , it finally worked , thanks for mr.crusha too ^^

Comment: @ToqaYousri ~ welcome to stackoverflow! glad to see you were provided with the solution, it it is customary here to then 'accept' the answer. this is done with the with the tick you should see to the left side of this answer. enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

As Crusha pointed out, check if the file exists before printing your output into it. For example:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\STUD_INFO.txt");
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\STUD_INFO.txt" , true);
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter (fw);
if (!f.exists()) {
    pw.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tSTUDENT INFORMATION");
    pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    pw.println("First_Name" + "\t\t    " + "Last_Name" + "\t\t    " + "Address" + "\t\t    " + "E_mail" + "\t\t    " + "Department" + "\t\t    " + "Password");
}
pw.println(First_Name   + "\t\t\t    " + Last_Name + "\t\t    " + Address + "\t\t    " + E_mail + "\t    " + Department + "\t\t\t    " + Password);
```